# Java gral add problem The method add(Comparable<?>[]) is ambiguous for the type DataTable

Tags: java, github, graph

I'm trying to run the example code from the gral wiki page on GitHub but when I use the data.add function I get the problem:

```
The method add(Comparable<?>[]) is ambiguous for the type DataTable
```

This is my code:

```
public Graph() 
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 600);


    DataTable data = new DataTable(Double.class, Double.class);
    for (double x = -5.0; x <= 5.0; x+=0.25) 
    {
        double y = 5.0*Math.sin(x);
        data.add(x,y);
    }

}
```

And I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: your code works just fine on my machine? What java version do you use?

Comment: my jdk is 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, the function add doesn't work with java 9.0.1 for some reason, so i had to downgrade to 8.1